# Hibernate Annotations Metadata

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection, annotations

is there a way how I can get MetaData about my Hibernate Annotations?

I need information about **Associations** if they are **nullable** or not.

Right now I can only query for `ClassMetadata`

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/metadata/ClassMetadata.html

Where I can run through the properties and check if it is a

`EntityType` 
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/EntityType.html

or `CollectionType`
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/CollectionType.html

`EntityType` apparently has a `isNullable` function but not `CollectionType`

So I thought about using the Annotation information

```
 @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "foreign", parameters = @Parameter(name = "property", value = "seizureI18n"))
 @Id
 @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
 @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
 public Integer getId() {
   return this.id;
 }
```

Is this possible or maybe another way to achieve what I want.

Regards

JS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure I understand your question, but if you want to see if an annotation is present you could do like this (using introspection):

```
Annotation[] tabAnnotation = A.class.getField( "fieldB" ).getDeclaredAnnotations( );
for( Annotation annotation : tabAnnotation )
   if( annotation instanceof Entity )
      System.out.println( ((Entity)annotation).isNullable() );
```

Answer (score 2):

A collection can't be nullable, by definition. A collection of n elements means there are n entities of the specified type that have a foreign key reference to this entity. It does not imply anything in this entity's table.

So the only relations you can check for nullability are *ToOne-relations (OneToOne, ManyToOne).

Comment: the default value for the annotation ``nullable`` is ``true`` at least according to **5.1.4.1.4. Declaring column attributes** of http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-properties